# Wildfly 26 elytron security domain config is not working

Tags: java, security, elytron, wildfly-26

I am trying to migrate an application to wildfly 26, and i am trying to use elytron to secure the application.

I successfully run this commands using the jboss cli

```
/subsystem=elytron/jdbc-realm=myapp-security-realm:add(principal-query=[{sql="select clave from admin.usuario where usuario = ?", data-source="SISMedicalDS", simple-digest-mapper={algorithm=simple-digest-sha-256,password-index=1}},{sql="select r.nombre, 'Roles' from admin.rol r join admin.perfil p on r.id = p.rol_id join admin.usuario u on u.id = p.usuario_id where u.usuario = ?", data-source="SISMedicalDS", attribute-mapping=[{index=1, to=roles}]}])

/subsystem=elytron/security-domain=myapp-security-domain:add(realms=[{realm=myapp-security-realm}], default-realm=myapp-security-realm, permission-mapper=default-permission-mapper)

/subsystem=elytron/http-authentication-factory=myapp-security-http:add(http-server-mechanism-factory=global, security-domain=myapp-security-domain, mechanism-configurations=[{mechanism-name=FORM}])

/subsystem=undertow/application-security-domain=myapp-application-security-domain:add(http-authentication-factory=myapp-security-http)
```

And i also changed my jboss-web.xml and web.xml files to the suggested configuration

jboss-web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE jboss-web>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/schema/jbossas/jboss-web_13_0.xsd"
               version="13.0">
    <security-domain>nmedical-application-security-domain</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

web.xml (login config only)

```
<login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>nmedical-application-security-domain</realm-name>       
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/login.jsp?error=true</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
```

When i try to deploy the application in the wildfly 26 server i always get this error

```
"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.security.security-domain.myapp-application-security-domain"]
```

I have checked the server console and under the web (undertow) subsystem i can see that the myapp-application-security-domain exists, so i really don't know what the problem might be

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

the namespace jboss.security.security-domain is related to the legacy security and not Elytron. Elytron is probably not enabled in some resource and that resource is referring to the `myapp-application-security-domain` as a legacy security domain and the error gets thrown.

Comment: when you say "some resource", are referring to the app i am deploying or the server ? The server is completely new by the way

Comment: What i can see in the logs is that these lines are present
"jboss.deployment.unit.\"nmedical-admin.war\".component.SeguridadServiceBean.CREATE is missing [jboss.security.security-domain.nmedical-application-security-domain]",
for every EJB Service i have, so i guess that the EJB subsystem must also be enabled for Elytron ???

Answer (score 0):

I finally have it working thanks to diavil response and this post:

[How to configure Elytron](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jbossas/jboss-security/how-to-configure-an-elytron-jaas-security-realm/)

What i ended up doing was configuring the security config named other both in the ejb3 and undertow subsystem; it's not a solution that i like too much but it is what it is